# reading cookie information and creating a string from it

Tags: javascript, string, cookies, split

In my site i save some cookies with **javascript** and jquery that have a name and some values (the first value is always a type) the cookie looks like this:

```
cookieName1=type,value2,value3 , cookieName2=type,value2,value3 ...
```

Now i need to loop through all cookies and build a string that will look like this:

```
cookieName1:type:value2,value3|cookieName2:type:value2,value3| ...
```

Can any one help me with doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
var cookies = "cookieName1=type,value2,value3 , cookieName2=type,value2,value3";
cookies = cookies.split(' , ');
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    cookies[i] = cookies[i].split('=').join(':');
}
cookies = cookies.join('|');

alert(cookies);
```